# Infinite loop problem with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having an odd issue I cannot solve by myself. I'm trying to construct step by step the curves of classical trigonometric functions, sine and cosine. Here is the code, which compilation does not end (if you try it, and encounter the same problem, break the compilation after frame 65). I'm using LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen,calc}
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=utf8}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,arrows.meta}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \def\xm{-6.4}
    \def\xM{6.4}
    \def\ym{-2}
    \def\yM{2}
    \def\xC{-3.14}
    \def\yC{4}
    \def\lastcount{0}
    \def\first{0}
    \def\second{0}

    \draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC) circle (1cm) ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ;

    \draw[color=gray] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
    \draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
    \draw [-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
    \draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
    \draw [very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
    \draw [very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

    \foreach \x/\label/\rx in {-6.28/$-2\pi$/.15, -4.71/$-\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, -3.14/$-\pi$/, -1.57/$-\dfrac\pi2$/, 0/$0$/0, 1.57/$\dfrac\pi2$/, 3.14/$\pi$/, 4.71/$\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, 6.28/$2\pi$/-.1} {
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\rx}{}}{\def\rx{0}}{}
        \draw[very thick, red] (\x,-.4ex) -- node [xshift=\rx cm, yshift=-1em, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt, opacity=.65, text opacity=1] {\scriptsize\label} (\x,.4ex) ;
    }

    \draw[very thick, green] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC) ;
    \draw[very thick, red] (\xC+1, \yC) -- (\xC+1, \yC) ;
    \pause

    \foreach [count=\i from 2, evaluate=\x as \y using sin(\x/3.1415*180), evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(\x/3.1415*180) ] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
        \draw<\i-64>[very thick, red] (0,0) -- (\x,0) ;
        \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!80!black, opacity=.6] (\x,0) -- (\x,\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[very thick, red, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:\x/3.1415*180:1) ;
        \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!80!black, opacity=.6] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC+\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[thin, dotted, gray] (\xC, \yC+\y) -- (\xC+\cosx, \yC+\y) ;
        \xdef\lastcount{\i} ;
        \node<\i> at (3,4) {\color{red}\lastcount} ;
    } ;
    \pgfmathparse{\lastcount+1}
    \let\lastcount\pgfmathresult

    \uncover<\lastcount->{
        \draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC) circle (1cm) ;
        \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
        \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ; }

    \foreach [count=\i from \lastcount, evaluate=\x as \y using sin(-\x/3.1415*180), evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(-\x/3.1415*180) ] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
        \draw<\i-64>[very thick, blue] (0,0) -- (-\x,0) ;
        \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!80!black, opacity=.6] (-\x,0) -- (-\x,\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[very thick, blue, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:-1*\x/3.1415*180:1) ;
        \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!80!black] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC+\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[thin, dotted, gray] (\xC, \yC+\y) -- (\xC+\cosx, \yC+\y) ;
        \xdef\lastcount{\i} ;
        \node<\i> at (3,4) {\color{blue}\lastcount} ;
    } ;
    \pgfmathparse{\lastcount+1}
    \let\second\pgfmathresult

    \onslide<\second>{\node at (5,4) {\color{red}\lastcount} ;}
     %    \draw<\lastcount->[ultra thick, orange, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(\x/3.1415*180)}) ;
    \draw<64>[ultra thick, orange, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(\x/3.1415*180)}) ;   \end{tikzpicture} \end{center} \end{frame}

\section{La fonction cosinus}

\begin{frame}
    Blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I also encounter one odd warning :
*Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into 
your preamble.* I checked the log created with \listfiles command, and if I correctly understand its contents, I'm using version 3.1.4 from TeXlive 2019 (installed in my home dir in Ubuntu 18.04).

Lastly, I'm having opacity issue in my code (lines 54 and 56, the vertical green bar).

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: You have to literally write ‘\pgfplotsset{compatriot=1.16}’ in the preamble of the document.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\usepackage{etex}`

Comment: are you _sure_ you want `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` ? that disables almost all of the features of luatex, it can be used in some special cases to get better compatibility with pdftex but it should almost never be used

Comment: I don't say I understand all the lines I put in my code ! I had to use etex many years ago in order to raise the number of registries TeX could use, if my memory is good. It may be useless now, but I had a very big hole (more than 10 years) in my usage of (La)TeX. I have very few ideas on how to update my knowledge and comprehension of moder relationship between all pieces of the (La)TeX system. I moved to LuaLaTeX 4 years ago, not for using Lua, but because it turned out it was the compiler that allowed me to use every tool I (believed I) needed...

Comment: @David Carlisle : could you please give me some advice on the right way to specify input and fonts ? I always have difficulties with symbol like €, which I do not understand why I should use a LaTeX command to write it... Thanks !

Comment: You can't really ask unrelated questions in comments, that's not how the site works, to get a  € you should just need to enter  € , if it doesn't ask a new question with an example @natsirt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have an infinite loop. There are many things that could be improved (`trig format=rad` etc.) but maybe this is a basis for further discussions. I added

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
```

and more importantly replaced the `\let\lastcount` stuff by `\edef...`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen,calc}
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=utf8}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \def\xm{-6.4}
    \def\xM{6.4}
    \def\ym{-2}
    \def\yM{2}
    \def\xC{-3.14}
    \def\yC{4}
    \def\lastcount{0}
    \def\first{0}
    \def\second{0}

    \draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC) circle [radius=1cm] ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ;

    \draw[color=gray] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
    \draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
    \draw [-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
    \draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
    \draw [very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
    \draw [very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

    \foreach \x/\label/\rx in {-6.28/$-2\pi$/.15, -4.71/$-\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, -3.14/$-\pi$/, -1.57/$-\dfrac\pi2$/, 0/$0$/0, 1.57/$\dfrac\pi2$/, 3.14/$\pi$/, 4.71/$\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, 6.28/$2\pi$/-.1} {
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\rx}{}}{\def\rx{0}}{}
        \draw[very thick, red] (\x,-.4ex) -- node [xshift=\rx cm, yshift=-1em, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt, opacity=.65, text opacity=1] {\scriptsize\label} (\x,.4ex) ;
    }

    \draw[very thick, green] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC) ;
    \draw[very thick, red] (\xC+1, \yC) -- (\xC+1, \yC) ;
    \pause

    \foreach [count=\i from 2, evaluate=\x as \y using sin(\x/3.1415*180), evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(\x/3.1415*180) ] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
        \draw<\i-64>[very thick, red] (0,0) -- (\x,0) ;
        \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!80!black, opacity=.6] (\x,0) -- (\x,\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[very thick, red, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:\x/3.1415*180:1) ;
        \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!80!black, opacity=.6] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC+\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[thin, dotted, gray] (\xC, \yC+\y) -- (\xC+\cosx, \yC+\y) ;
        \xdef\mylastcount{\i} ;
        \node<\i> at (3,4) {\color{red}\mylastcount} ;
    } ;
    \edef\lastcount{\the\numexpr\mylastcount+1}

    \uncover<\lastcount->{
        \draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC)  [radius=1cm] ;
        \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
        \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ; }

    \foreach [count=\i from \lastcount, evaluate=\x as \y using sin(-\x/3.1415*180), evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(-\x/3.1415*180) ] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
        \draw<\i-64>[very thick, blue] (0,0) -- (-\x,0) ;
        \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!80!black, opacity=.6] (-\x,0) -- (-\x,\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[very thick, blue, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:-1*\x/3.1415*180:1) ;
        \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!80!black] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC+\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[thin, dotted, gray] (\xC, \yC+\y) -- (\xC+\cosx, \yC+\y) ;
        \xdef\mylastcount{\i} ;
        \node<\i> at (3,4) {\color{blue}\lastcount} ;
    } ;
    \edef\second{\the\numexpr\mylastcount+1}

    \onslide<\second>{\node at (5,4) {\color{red}\lastcount} ;}
     %    \draw<\lastcount->[ultra thick, orange, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(\x/3.1415*180)}) ;
    \draw<64>[ultra thick, orange, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(\x/3.1415*180)}) ;   
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}

\section{La fonction cosinus}

\begin{frame}
    Blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Fixed a typo.

Comment: I will try your code under minutes. Thanks !

Comment: OK, now compilation process ends up. But the drawing of the curve occurs both sides at the same time. I wanted it to be sequential : first between 0 and 2pi, then between 0 and -2pi. I believe it is more natural for young pupils to start from 0 rad angle, and move « forward » around the trigonometric circle, then return to 0 and go « backward », seeing the variation of the y-value of the point moving on the circle. Having both values of x and -x varying complicates the viewing. That's why I tried to play, in my initial code, with counter to have the two parts drawn successively.

Comment: @natsirt I am busy right now but I did not really change the relative ordering. I can do that later. (The code is IMHO unnecessarily complicated, if you describe what you want to get there will be a simpler version.)

Comment: Many thanks, I found the reason why it doesn't work as it (almost 0:-) !) did. Just a typo you left when modifying my code (the first  \edef\lastcount{\the\numexpr\mylastcount+1} --> \edef\lastcount{\the\numexpr\mylastcount+1} ). I really appreciate your efforts, and I will willingly learn how to simplify this code. I must admit I do not practise TikZ often enough to get some intuition on how to do things the right way, or just a good way. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've finally reached (with some difficulties) something that suits my needs. I post here the relevant code, just for sharing, and also with the hope that someone will have enough time to show me how to improve the code. It was especially hard for me to cope with tests involving floating point number comparisons, and also arrow tips in conjunction with opacity (I finally gave up, as scope + transparency group does not work well with Beamer frames using remember picture and overlay option... and I had strange behavior of TikZ when moving arrow tips, at extremity of curves, at the end of the document, line 369 for example, when using shorten >=-1.5mm for example). Thanks in advance !

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen,calc}
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=utf8}
\usepackage{amsmath, pgfplots, numprint}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\section{La fonction sinus}

\begin{frame}

\vspace*{3cm}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \def\xm{-6.4}
    \def\xM{6.4}
    \def\ym{-2}
    \def\yM{2}
    \def\xC{-3.14}
    \def\yC{4}
    \def\lastcount{0}

    \draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC) circle (1cm) ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ;

    \draw[color=gray] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
    \draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
    \draw[-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
    \draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
    \draw[very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
    \draw[very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

    \foreach \x/\label/\rx in {-6.28/$-2\pi$/.15, -4.71/$-\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, -3.14/$-\pi$/, -1.57/$-\dfrac\pi2$/, 0/$0$/0, 1.57/$\dfrac\pi2$/, 3.14/$\pi$/, 4.71/$\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, 6.28/$2\pi$/-.1} {
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\rx}{}}{\def\rx{0}}{}
        \draw[very thick, red] (\x,-.4ex) -- node [xshift=\rx cm, yshift=-1em, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt, opacity=.65, text opacity=1] {\scriptsize\label} (\x,.4ex) ;
    }

    \draw[very thick, green] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC) ;
    \draw[very thick, red] (\xC+1, \yC) -- (\xC+1, \yC) ;
    \pause

    \foreach [count=\i from 2, evaluate=\x as \y using sin(deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \a using deg(\x)] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
        % Les abscisses sur l'axe (Ox) du repère orthonormé où est tracée la fonction sinus :
        \draw<\i-64>[very thick, red] (0,0) -- (\x,0) ;
        % La valeur de sin(x) en ordonnée dans le repère orthonormé où est tracée la fonction sinus :
        \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (\x,0) -- (\x,\y) ;
        % L'arc de cercle orienté de longueur x sur le cercle trigonométrique :
        \draw<\i>[very thick, red, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:\a:1) ;
        % La mesure x de cet arc de cercle orienté, affichée à proximité de la flèche orientant l'arc :
        \draw<\i> [red] (\xC,\yC) ++ (\a:1.5) node[font=\tiny, inner sep=.5pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1] {$x=\numprint{\x}$} ;
        % Le trait joignant le centre du cercle trigonométrique au point de ce cercle repéré par le réel x :
        \draw<\i> [thin, gray] (\xC,\yC) -- ++ (\a:1) ;
        % Le marquage (secteur angulaire coloré) de l'angle de mesure x :
        \filldraw<\i> [red, opacity=.25] (\xC,\yC) -- (\xC+.5,\yC) arc (0:\a:.5) -- cycle ;
        % La matérialisation de la grandeur sin(x) sur le repère orthonormé attaché au centre du cercle trigonométrique :
        \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC+\y) ;
        % Le trait permettant de montrer que le point repéré sur le cercle trigonométrique par le réel x a pour ordonnée sin(x) :
        \draw<\i>[thin, dashed, gray] (\xC, \yC+\y) -- (\xC+\cosx, \yC+\y) ;
        % Des traits fins permettant de matérialiser le passage du repère attaché au cercle trigonométrique au repère où l'on trace la fonction sinus :
        \draw<\i>[very thin, dashed, green!70!black] (\xC,\yC) -- (\x,0) ;
        \draw<\i>[very thin, dashed, green!70!black] (\xC,\yC+\y) -- (\x,\y) ;
        \xdef\lastcount{\i} ;
        \node<\i>[text width=7cm] at (3,4) {Tracé de la fonction $\sin : x \longmapsto \sin x$\\ pour $x\in[0\,;2\pi]$} ;
    } ;
    \edef\lastcount{\the\numexpr\lastcount+1}

    \uncover<\lastcount->{
        \draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC) circle (1cm) ;
        \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
        \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ; }

    \foreach [count=\i from \lastcount, evaluate=\x as \y using sin(-deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(-deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \a using -deg(\x)] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
        \draw<\i-64>[very thick, blue] (0,0) -- (-\x,0) ;
        \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (-\x,0) -- (-\x,\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[very thick, blue, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:\a:1) ;
        \draw<\i> [blue] (\xC,\yC) ++ (\a:1.5) node[font=\tiny, inner sep=.5pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1] {$x=\numprint{-\x}$} ;
        \draw<\i> [thin, gray] (\xC,\yC) -- ++ (\a:1) ;
        \filldraw<\i> [blue, opacity=.25] (\xC,\yC) -- (\xC+.5,\yC) arc (0:\a:.5) -- cycle ;
        \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC, \yC+\y) ;
        \draw<\i>[thin, dashed, gray] (\xC, \yC+\y) -- (\xC+\cosx, \yC+\y) ;
        \xdef\lastcount{\i} ;
        \node<\i>[text width=7cm] at (3,4) {Tracé de la fonction $\sin : x \longmapsto \sin x$\\ pour $x\in[-2\pi\,;0]$} ;
    } ;
    \edef\lastcount{\the\numexpr\lastcount+1}

    \draw<\lastcount-65>[ultra thick, orange, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
    \node<65>[text width=7cm] at (3,4) {Tracé de la fonction $\sin : x \longmapsto \sin x$\\ pour $x\in[-2\pi\,;2\pi]$} ;
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\section{La fonction cosinus}

\begin{frame}

\vspace*{3cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\def\xm{-6.4}
\def\xM{6.4}
\def\ym{-2}
\def\yM{2}
\def\xC{-3.14}
\def\yC{4}
\def\lastcount{0}

\draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC) circle (1cm) ;
\draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
\draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ;

\draw[color=gray] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
\draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
\draw[very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
\draw[very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

\foreach \x/\label/\rx in {-6.28/$-2\pi$/.15, -4.71/$-\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, -3.14/$-\pi$/, -1.57/$-\dfrac\pi2$/, 0/$0$/0, 1.57/$\dfrac\pi2$/, 3.14/$\pi$/, 4.71/$\dfrac{3\pi}2$/, 6.28/$2\pi$/-.1} {
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\rx}{}}{\def\rx{0}}{}
    \draw[very thick, red] (\x,-.4ex) -- node [xshift=\rx cm, yshift=-1em, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt, opacity=.65, text opacity=1] {\scriptsize\label} (\x,.4ex) ;
}

\draw<1>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC+1, \yC) ;
\draw[very thick, red] (\xC+1, \yC) -- (\xC+1, \yC) ;
\draw<1-64>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (0, 0) -- (0, 1) ;

\pause

\foreach [count=\i from 2, evaluate=\x as \y using cos(deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \sinx using sin(deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \a using deg(\x)] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
    \draw<\i-64>[very thick, red] (0,0) -- (\x,0) ;
    \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (\x,0) -- (\x,\y) ;
    \draw<\i>[very thick, red, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:\a:1) ;
    \draw<\i>[red] (\xC,\yC) ++ (\a:1.5) node[font=\tiny, inner sep=.5pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1] {$x=\numprint{\x}$} ;
    \draw<\i>[thin, gray] (\xC,\yC) -- ++ (\a:1) ;
    \filldraw<\i> [red, opacity=.25] (\xC,\yC) -- (\xC+.5,\yC) arc (0:\a:.5) -- cycle ;
    \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC+\y, \yC) ;
    \draw<\i>[thin, dashed, gray] (\xC+\y, \yC) -- (\xC+\y, \yC+\sinx) ;
    % Des traits fins permettant de matérialiser le passage du repère attaché au cercle trigonométrique au repère où l'on trace la fonction sinus :
    \draw<\i>[very thin, dashed, green!70!black] (\xC,\yC) to[bend right] (\x,0) ;
    \draw<\i>[very thin, dashed, green!70!black] (\xC+\y,\yC) to[bend right] (\x,\y) ;
    \xdef\lastcount{\i} ;
    \node<\i>[text width=7cm] at (3,4) {Tracé de la fonction $\cos : x \longmapsto \cos x$\\ pour $x\in[0\,;2\pi]$} ;
} ;
\edef\lastcount{\the\numexpr\lastcount+1}

\uncover<\lastcount->{
    \draw[very thick] (\xC, \yC) circle (1cm) ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC-1.5, \yC) -- (\xC+1.5, \yC) ;
    \draw[thick, -Stealth] (\xC, \yC-1.5) -- (\xC, \yC+1.5) ; }

\foreach [count=\i from \lastcount, evaluate=\x as \y using cos(-deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \sinx using sin(-deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \a using -deg(\x)] \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6.0,6.2} {
    \draw<\i-64>[very thick, blue] (0,0) -- (-\x,0) ;
    \draw<\i-64>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (-\x,0) -- (-\x,\y) ;
    \draw<\i>[very thick, blue, -stealth] (\xC, \yC) ++(0:1) arc (0:\a:1) ;
    \draw<\i> [blue] (\xC,\yC) ++ (\a:1.5) node[font=\tiny, inner sep=.5pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1] {$x=\numprint{-\x}$} ;
    \draw<\i> [thin, gray] (\xC,\yC) -- ++ (\a:1) ;
    \filldraw<\i> [blue, opacity=.25] (\xC,\yC) -- (\xC+.5,\yC) arc (0:\a:.5) -- cycle ;
    \draw<\i>[ultra thick, green!70!black, opacity=.6] (\xC, \yC) -- (\xC+\y, \yC) ;
    \draw<\i>[thin, dashed, gray] (\xC+\y, \yC) -- (\xC+\y, \yC+\sinx) ;
    \xdef\lastcount{\i} ;
    \node<\i>[text width=7cm] at (3,4) {Tracé de la fonction $\cos : x \longmapsto \cos x$\\ pour $x\in[-2\pi\,;0]$} ;
} ;
\edef\lastcount{\the\numexpr\lastcount+1}

\draw<\lastcount-65>[ultra thick, orange, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
\node<65>[text width=7cm] at (3,4) {Tracé de la fonction $\cos : x \longmapsto \cos x$\\ pour $x\in[-2\pi\,;2\pi]$} ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\section{Comparaison des courbes représentatives des fonction sinus et cosinus}

\begin{frame}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\def\xm{-6.4}
\def\xM{6.4}
\def\ym{-2}
\def\yM{2}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}  % Pour que les affichages des nombres générés par PGF/TikZ se fassent avec une virgule et non un point !

\draw[color=gray] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
\draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
\draw[very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
\draw[very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

\draw[ultra thick, orange!50!red, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!50!red] at (4.7,-1.3) {$y=\sin x$} ;
\draw[ultra thick, orange!75!yellow, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!75!yellow] at (5.6,1.2) {$y=\cos x$} ;

\node<2->[text width=10cm, align=center] at (0,4) {$2\pi$--périodicité de la fonction \textbf{sinus} :\\ pour tout $x\in\mathbb{R}$, on a $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x$} ;

%        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{ypos}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(sin(deg(#1))<0) ? -.2 : .2}} % Ne fonctionne pas
\foreach [count=\i from 3, evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \sinx using sin(deg(\x)) ] \x in {-6,-5.8,...,0} {
\draw<\i>[thick, opacity=.8, blue, {Circle[length=2pt]}-{Stealth}, shorten <=-1pt ] (\x, \sinx) -- node[inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $2\pi$} (\x+6.28, \sinx) ;
\node<\i>[circle, fill=blue, inner sep=1pt] (f) at (0,\sinx) {} ;
%  Nécessaire pour des arrondis corrects, autrement -4,8 donne -4,79999
\def\X{\pgfmathparse{\x}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}}
% Pas moyen de faire autrement pour comparer des nombres décimaux. S'il y a plus simple, je n'ai pas trouvé !
\ifnum\dimexpr\sinx pt\relax>0pt\relax
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x, 0) node[yshift=-.2cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x=\X$} -- (\x, \sinx) ;
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x+6.28, 0) node[yshift=-.2cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x+2\pi$} -- (\x+6.28, \sinx) ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f1) at (-.75, 2.5) {\scriptsize $\sin x$} ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f2) at (.75, 2.5) {\scriptsize $\sin(x+2\pi)$} ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f1.south) -- (f.north west) ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f2.south) -- (f.north east) ;
\else
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x, 0) node[yshift=.2cm, inner sep=.05pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x=\X$} -- (\x, \sinx) ;
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x+6.28, 0) node[yshift=.2cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x+2\pi$} -- (\x+6.28, \sinx) ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f1) at (-.75, -2.5) {\scriptsize $\sin x$} ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f2) at (.75, -2.5) {\scriptsize $\sin (x+2\pi)$} ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f1.north) -- (f.south west) ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f2.north) -- (f.south east) ;
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\def\xm{-6.4}
\def\xM{6.4}
\def\ym{-2}
\def\yM{2}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}  % Pour que les affichages des nombres générés par PGF/TikZ se fassent avec une virgule et non un point !

\draw[color=gray] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
\draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,\ym) grid (\xM,\yM);
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
\draw[very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
\draw[very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

\draw[ultra thick, orange!50!red, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!50!red] at (4.7,-1.3) {$y=\sin x$} ;
\draw[ultra thick, orange!75!yellow, opacity=.8, domain=-6.28:6.28,smooth,samples=200] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!75!yellow] at (5.6,1.2) {$y=\cos x$} ;

\node<2->[text width=10cm, align=center] at (0,4) {$2\pi$--périodicité de la fonction \textbf{cosinus} :\\ pour tout $x\in\mathbb{R}$, on a $\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos x$} ;

%    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{ypos}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(sin(deg(#1))<0) ? -.2 : .2}} % Ne fonctionne pas
\foreach [count=\i from 3, evaluate=\x as \cosx using cos(deg(\x)), evaluate=\x as \sinx using sin(deg(\x)) ] \x in {-6,-5.8,...,0} {
\draw<\i>[thick, opacity=.8, blue, {Circle[length=2pt]}-{Stealth}, shorten <=-1pt ] (\x, \cosx) -- node[inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $2\pi$} (\x+6.28, \cosx) ;
\node<\i>[circle, fill=blue, inner sep=1pt] (f) at (0,\cosx) {} ;
% Nécessaire pour des arrondis corrects, autrement -4,8 donne -4,79999
\def\X{\pgfmathparse{\x}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}}
% Pas moyen de faire autrement pour comparer des nombres décimaux. S'il y a plus simple, je n'ai pas trouvé !
\ifnum\dimexpr\cosx pt\relax>0pt\relax
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x, 0) node[yshift=-.2cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x=\X$} -- (\x, \cosx) ;
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x+6.28, 0) node[yshift=-.2cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x+2\pi$} -- (\x+6.28, \cosx) ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f1) at (-.75, 2.5) {\scriptsize $\cos x$} ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f2) at (.75, 2.5) {\scriptsize $\cos(x+2\pi)$} ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f1.south) -- (f.north west) ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f2.south) -- (f.north east) ;
\else
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x, 0) node[yshift=.2cm, inner sep=.05pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x=\X$} -- (\x, \cosx) ;
\draw<\i>[thin, blue, dashed] (\x+6.28, 0) node[yshift=.2cm, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] {\scriptsize $x+2\pi$} -- (\x+6.28, \cosx) ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f1) at (-.75, -2.5) {\scriptsize $\cos x$} ;
\node<\i>[blue, inner sep=1pt, fill=white, fill opacity=.8] (f2) at (.75, -2.5) {\scriptsize $\cos (x+2\pi)$} ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f1.north) -- (f.south west) ;
\draw<\i>[-stealth, blue, shorten >=2pt] (f2.north) -- (f.south east) ;
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, xscale=.5, yscale=2]
\def\xm{-12.8}
\def\xM{12.8}
\def\ym{-1.25}
\def\yM{1.5}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}  % Pour que les affichages des nombres générés par PGF/TikZ se fassent avec une virgule et non un point !

\draw[color=gray] (\xm,-1) grid (\xM,1);
\draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,-1) grid (\xM,1);
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
\draw[very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
\draw[very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

\draw[ultra thick, orange!75!yellow, opacity=.2, domain=\xm:\xM,smooth,samples=400] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!75!yellow, opacity=.2] at (5.6,1.2) {$y=\cos x$} ;

\node[text width=10cm, align=center] at (0,2) {$2\pi$--périodicité de la fonction \textbf{sinus} :\\
reproduction de motifs de longueur $2\pi$\\
\emph{\scriptsize(\textbf{attention : }le repère n'est plus orthonormé ici !)}} ;

\foreach[count=\k from 2, evaluate=\i as \m using -12.56+\i*6.28, evaluate=\i as \M using -12.56+(\i+1)*6.28] \i in {0,...,3} {
\draw<\k-5>[line width=1.5mm, blue!50!white, domain=\m:\M, smooth, samples=200, {|}-{|}, shorten <=0mm, shorten >=0mm] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
}

\foreach[count=\k from 6, evaluate=\i as \m using -10.996+\i*6.28, evaluate=\i as \M using -10.996+(\i+1)*6.28] \i in {0,...,3} {
\draw<\k-9>[line width=1.5mm, green!50!black, domain=\m:\M, smooth, samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
\draw<\k-9>[line width=1.5mm, green!50!black, ] (\m+.151, .8) -- (\m+.151, 1.16) ;
\draw<\k-9>[line width=1.5mm, green!50!black, ] (\M-.151, .8) -- (\M-.151, 1.16) ;
}

\foreach[count=\k from 10, evaluate=\i as \m using -12+\i*6.28, evaluate=\i as \M using -12+(\i+1)*6.28] \i in {0,...,3} {
\draw<\k-13>[line width=1.5mm, orange!50!pink, domain=\m:\M, smooth, samples=200, {|}-{|}, shorten <=0mm, shorten >=0mm] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
}    

\draw[ultra thick, orange!50!red, opacity=.8, domain=\xm:\xM,smooth,samples=400] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!50!red] at (4.7,-1.3) {$y=\sin x$} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, xscale=.5, yscale=2]
\def\xm{-12.8}
\def\xM{12.8}
\def\ym{-1.25}
\def\yM{1.5}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}  % Pour que les affichages des nombres générés par PGF/TikZ se fassent avec une virgule et non un point !

\draw[color=gray] (\xm,-1) grid (\xM,1);
\draw[help lines, step=.2, color=gray, opacity=.5] (\xm,-1) grid (\xM,1);
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (\xm,0)--(\xM,0) node[xshift=-.5ex, yshift=1.3ex, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$x$} ;
\draw[-Stealth, thick] (0,\ym)--(0,\yM) node[left, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt]{$y$};
\draw[very thick] (1,-.4ex) -- node [yshift=-.9em, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (1,.4ex) ;
\draw[very thick] (-.4ex,1) -- node [shift={(-1.2ex,1.2ex)}, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.1pt] {$1$} (.4ex,1) ; % =-1cm and -1cm

\draw[ultra thick, orange!50!red, opacity=.2, domain=\xm:\xM,smooth,samples=400] plot (\x, {sin(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!50!red, opacity=.2] at (4.7,-1.3) {$y=\sin x$} ;

\node[text width=10cm, align=center] at (0,2) {$2\pi$--périodicité de la fonction \textbf{cosinus} :\\
reproduction de motifs de longueur $2\pi$\\
\emph{\scriptsize(\textbf{attention : }le repère n'est plus orthonormé ici !)}} ;

\foreach[count=\k from 2, evaluate=\i as \m using -12.56+\i*6.28, evaluate=\i as \M using -12.56+(\i+1)*6.28] \i in {0,...,3} {
\draw<\k-5>[line width=1.5mm, blue!50!white, domain=\m:\M, smooth, samples=200, shorten <=0mm, shorten >=0mm] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
\draw<\k-5>[line width=1.5mm, blue!50!white] (\m+.151, .8) -- (\m+.151, 1.16) ;
\draw<\k-5>[line width=1.5mm, blue!50!white] (\M-.151, .8) -- (\M-.151, 1.16) ;
}

\foreach[count=\k from 6, evaluate=\i as \m using -10.996+\i*6.28, evaluate=\i as \M using -10.996+(\i+1)*6.28] \i in {0,...,3} {
\draw<\k-9>[line width=1.5mm, green!50!black, domain=\m:\M, smooth, samples=200, {|}-{|}] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
}

\foreach[count=\k from 10, evaluate=\i as \m using -12+\i*6.28, evaluate=\i as \M using -12+(\i+1)*6.28] \i in {0,...,3} {
\draw<\k-13>[line width=1.5mm, orange!50!red, domain=\m:\M, smooth, samples=200, {|}-{|}, shorten <=0mm, shorten >=0mm] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
}    

\draw[ultra thick, orange!75!yellow, opacity=1, domain=\xm:\xM,smooth,samples=400] plot (\x, {cos(deg(\x))}) ;
\node[orange!75!yellow, opacity=1] at (5.6,1.2) {$y=\cos x$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```